# "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" when trying to start grails App in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, debian

I have a problem with a grails app I'm working on and I can't figure it out. 
It's a grails 2.0 app that should run on a Debian stable with a Tomcat7. So I built the war file and deployed it to the Tomcat. As soon as I start it, I get the following log output in the Tomcat logfile (catalina.out):

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
28-Jan-2012 13:02:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
28-Jan-2012 13:02:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Gibbons5] startup failed due to previous errors
28-Jan-2012 13:02:00 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Gibbons5] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

I tried making the output a little more verbose by increasing the Tomcats loglevel to FINEST but that doesn't give me any more information. Also I changed the app's loglevel to debug, but that doesn't help either.

On my local Tomcat everything works fine with the same war and a Tomcat7.

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.18'
    }
}

codenarc.reports = {
    XMLReport('xml') {
        outputFile = 'CodeNarcReport.xml'
        title = 'Gibbons5'
    }
    HTMLReport('html') {
    outputFile = 'CodeNarcReport.html'
        title = 'Gibbons5'
        }
}
codenarc.propertiesFile = 'codenarc.properties'

// cobertura exclusions
coverage {
    exclusions = [
        '**/BuildConfig*',
        '**/*SecurityConfig*'
    ]
}
```

application.properties

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Tue Jan 03 23:21:41 CET 2012
app.context=/
app.grails.version=2.0.0
app.name=Gibbons5
app.servlet.version=2.5
app.version=0.1
plugins.burning-image=0.5.0
plugins.code-coverage=1.2.5
plugins.codenarc=0.16.1
plugins.hibernate=2.0.0
plugins.joda-time=1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
plugins.jquery=1.7.1
plugins.svn=1.0.1
plugins.syntax-highlighter=0.1.4
plugins.tomcat=2.0.0
```

BootStrap.groovy

import grails.util.GrailsUtil

```
class BootStrap {

    def baseDataGenerator

    def init = { servletContext ->
        switch (GrailsUtil.environment) {
            case 'development':
                log.debug("init() - booting as development")

                baseDataGenerator.generateData()

                break

            case 'production':
                log.info("init() - booting as production")

                baseDataGenerator.generateData()

                break

            case 'test':
                log.debug("init() - booting as test")

                baseDataGenerator.generateData()

                break

            default:
                log.warn("init() - uncovered environment " + GrailsUtil.environment)
        }
    }

    def destroy = {}
}
```

Comment: Can have multiple reasons and most probably this is because of a plugin-dependency which requires servlet 3.0 API, which only works for tomcat 7. Please provide your BuildConfig.groovy and your application.properties

Comment: I have also seen this when hibernate is unable to connect to the database.  You should turn up the app's loglevel to log the grails classes.

Comment: @chrislovecnm: I tried that and turned them all to debug but the app isn't logging anything yet.

Comment: @crudolf: Tomcat7 is giving me the same output :(

Comment: Please Show your bootstrap.groovy

Comment: @crudolf: Done. It's calling a DataGenerator which is adding 5 rows into the database, but according to the empty log it's not getting there anyway.

Comment: So, I just tried it on a different server and it's working in Tomcat6 as well as in Tomcat7. Guess I have to go through all the server settings again.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting the same error, but I found the following article:

http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/

In resume, you need to create a logging.properties file in your WEB-INF/classes (you can add it to exploded folder inside webapps and restart tomcat)

The content of logging.properties can be:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

After restart Tomcat you can see more detailed errors.

Comment: FYI... you need to put this file in /grails-app/conf in order to get it deployed to the right directory.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same type of error in Tomcat7.  I found that if I followed the instructions on converting Tomcat to use log4j it could capture the early errors to the logs, but with the default Tomcat config if an error occurs early in the startup process of the Grails app the "Error listenerStart" is all you get.

Some sources of this:

1. Datasource being set to dbCreate:validate, and the DB being out-of-sync w/ GORM domain classes.
2. Errors in BootStrap.groovy, mostly related to trying to auto-create a domain object that already existed due to previous run.
3. Other configuration errors (less likely.